# How to get a sum from a Django filter query

Tags: django, filter, sum

I have used the following query, and I am trying to get the Sum of 'fee'

```
reg_total_fees =orders.aggregate(all_sum=Sum('par_payment__fee'))
```

but I get this:
{'all_sum': 1785}

Do you know how I could just get the value?

Answer (score 1):

```
reg_total_fees =orders.aggregate(all_sum=Sum('par_payment__fee'))['all_sum']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just access the key 'all_sum' from dictionary reg_total_fees.Below line will give you the value you need.

```
reg_total_fees =orders.aggregate(all_sum=Sum('par_payment__fee'))['all_sum']
```

Answer (score 0):

reg_total_fees = orders.objects.filter(write your interesting attribute for filtering =expected value for filttering).aggregate(Sum('par_payment__fee'))['par_payment__fee__sum']